# Symfony Project, can't fixing file permissions

Tags: php, composer-php, symfony

I regularly get file permissions errors when I try to update composer or to clear cache of my symfony project.
Yet my files are set correctly according to the doc of symfony : http://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/file_permissions.html

I'am under linux, Manjaro Budgie edition (last stable version)
server apache last version

For example :

```
composer update
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Nothing to install or update
Generating autoload files
> Incenteev\ParameterHandler\ScriptHandler::buildParameters
Updating the "app/config/parameters.yml" file
> Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap
> Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler::clearCache

 // Clearing the cache for the dev environment with debug true                                                          

  [Symfony\Component\Filesystem\Exception\IOException]                                                                                                                                                
  Failed to remove file "/srv/http/PetitMur/var/cache/de~/annotations/1a/5b504d5c506c6174666f726d42756e646c655c456e746974795c41727469636c652474616773405b416e6e6f745d5d5b315d.doctrinecache.data": .
```

This file has this rights :

```
pierre $ la /srv/http/PetitMur/var/cache/de~/annotations...data
-rw-rw-r--+ 1 http http 234 29.09.2016 18:13 /srv/http/PetitMur/var/cache/de~/annotations...data
```

I know, this problem is recurrent. But I have already set the permission file according to the doc of symfony. Currently I have to run command on super user to make it work and this isn't normal.

You have an idea ?

edit :

```
php bin/symfony_requirements

Symfony Requirements Checker
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

> PHP is using the following php.ini file:
  /etc/php/php.ini

> Checking Symfony requirements:
  .............................WW......


 [OK]                                         
 Your system is ready to run Symfony projects 


Optional recommendations to improve your setup
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

 * intl extension should be available
   > Install and enable the intl extension (used for validators).

 * a PHP accelerator should be installed
   > Install and/or enable a PHP accelerator (highly recommended).


Note  The command console could use a different php.ini file
~~~~  than the one used with your web server. To be on the
      safe side, please check the requirements from your web
      server using the web/config.php script.
```

Comment: have you tried clearing using rm -rf var/cache/*?

Comment: Yes, but after some time the problem back.

Comment: Which web server? Is it Apache?

Comment: Also, which distro of Linux please.

Comment: Is any of your code loaded via a compiler pass?

Comment: I have edit my question. Liam Sorsby, I don't understand, what do you mean about compiler pass ?

Comment: @PierreDommerc http://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/compiler_passes.html

Comment: I'm not sure if this is related, but can you run from the directory `/srv/http/PetitMur` this command: `php bin/symfony_requirements` and see if that shows any issues.

Comment: the file is owned by user htttp, does your clearCache command run under root?... maybe it's an issue of user permissons and not file permissions

Comment: @Liam Sorsby no.  Alvin Bunk I have edit my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have try this "sudo chown -R http:pierre Myproject" and for the moment this works for clear the cache but not for composer.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect permission and possibly user group settings may be incorrect.

Go into your Apache httpd.conf file to check the User/Group settings. You'll see lines like this:

```
User apache
Group apache
```

The above was from my system which is CentOS 6, and httpd.conf is under `/etc/httpd/conf/` folder. Yours may be in a different location and may be the user `httpd` instead (check it).

Then set the proper user/group for your Symfony3 project:

```
sudo chown -R apache:apache /srv/http/PetitMur
```

The above command sets the user:group both to `apache`, you may have to use `httpd`

Now delete your old cache files & logs, since they may have been created before with the wrong user:

```
sudo rm -rf var/cache/*
sudo rm -rf var/logs/*
```

Then run the setfacl again, make sure you cut & paste (there is a capital X) and use the correct user (either apache or httpd):

```
$ sudo setfacl -R -m u:apache:rwX -m u:`whoami`:rwX var
$ sudo setfacl -dR -m u:apache:rwX -m u:`whoami`:rwX var
```

Then test out your system and see it the problem got fixed.

Comment: In my case the User and Group is "http" in my hhtpd.conf. And I tell you I have already try this before... But for you I have try again and =>        pierre $ composer update
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Nothing to install or update
 [ErrorException]                                                             
  file_put_contents(/srv/http/PetitMur/vendor/composer/installed.json): faile  
  d to open stream: Permission denied

Comment: And           =>                    pierre $ la /srv/http/PetitMur/vendor/composer/installed.json
-rw-r--r-- 1 http http 81281 29.09.2016 19:50 /srv/http/PetitMur/vendor/composer

Comment: Have you tried: `sudo composer update`??? You may have to point to the location of composer. Use `whereis composer` to find it.

Comment: Quote from above "Currently I have to run command on super user to make it work and this isn't normal." And my binary composer have this rights : -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 1704783 17.09.2016 13:56 /usr/bin/composer*

Comment: Hi Pierre. This is an issue with your privileges on the system, since you need to use `sudo` on your system. Are you the admin? If not, you may need to check with your admin and grant you the appropriate privileges to make you an admin user. See my [exact same question on a Laravel install using composer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36672923/how-to-install-laravel-as-apache-user).

Comment: Yes it's my PC, I can switch on root user, but is not normal. You say "sudo chown -R apache:apache /srv/http/PetitMur". But with that all files/directory of my project are locked and editable only by http user and group => with phpStorm all file are locked. So explain me how you work on a project with that ?

Comment: Yes, I have the exact same problem, and that's why I posted the question. The same problem for me exists in our Production environment. I have a separate Development environment in which I use the root user to login. I also use Eclipse as an IDE, but it uses the root user in the Development environment. Then I use SCP to copy files from the Development environment to the Production machine in my `home` directory. Then on the Production machine I copy from my `home` directory to the apache DocumentRoot, after that I us `sudo chmod -R apache:apache /var/www/html/SymfonyRoot`. This works ok.